# Is there an equivalent for Aero Snap for windows in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm running Windows 7 and find Aero Snap really useful.  However, I can't find a way to perform the same action within Excel 2010.  Is that something that's possible to do?

If I have two spreadsheets open, then I can get equivalent results by Arrange All > Tile Vertically.  But I might have five different spreadsheets open, and want to view two of them side by side.  Is there a shortcut to do this?  Or is this a feature if I upgrade to a higher version of Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is: upgrade to Office 2013.

Within Excel 2010, the only way to approach this functionality is to have two separate workbooks, and use View -> Arrange All -> Vertical.

In Excel 2013, each spreadsheet is in a separate window from other spreadsheets.  That means you can do Aero Snap on them like any other application and (a significant improvement over 2010) if you're running a multiple-monitor set up, you can put some Excel windows in one screen and the rest in another, whereas in 2010 there was no way to do this, apart from stretching the main Excel window across both screens, which is untidy and spreads the ribbon and menu bars inconveniently wide.

Comment: You can always open multiple Excel instances, even with Excel 2010 (and probably pretty much every earlier version too).

Comment: But copy and paste between different Excel instances didn't work as well as within the same instance (I'm now on 2013 and can't go back to verify on a 2010 version)